# WPF ListView GridView GridViewColumn StringFormat CodeBehind .NET 4.0 Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, binding, string-formatting

Need to format a string in a ListView GridView in code behind.  XAML is not an option as the data and columns are created in code.

The XAML version of the desired date format is:

```
   <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Path=DateTime, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt}}" />
```

In this case I cannot use XAML as the number of columns varies and the columns that need to display a date in that format varies.  I just cannot figure out how to apply that date format in code behind.   Below is working code behind to build the columns.

```
    GridViewColumn gvc;
    GridViewColumnHeader gvch;
    Binding gvBinding;
    DataTemplate template;
    FrameworkElementFactory textblock;

    // Data Column
    gvc = new GridViewColumn();
    gvch = new GridViewColumnHeader();
    gvch.Content = SF.DispName;
    gvch.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    gvch.VerticalContentAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
    gvch.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
    gvc.Header = gvch;
    gvBinding = new Binding();
    gvBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    gvBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("[" + (sDocBaseResultDocsFieldsIndex * 2).ToString() + "]");
    template = new DataTemplate();
    textblock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    textblock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, gvBinding);
    // textblock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextTrimmingProperty, TextTrimming.WordEllipsis);
    template.VisualTree = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
    template.VisualTree.AppendChild(textblock);
    gvc.CellTemplate = template;
    gvSrchResultsScore.Columns.Add(gvc);

    sDocBaseResultDocsFieldsIndex++;
```

What I need to add is something like below but cannot figure it out.  I have tried every permutation of {}{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt}} that I can think of.

```
    if (sDocBaseResultDocsFieldsIndex == 12) gvBinding.StringFormat = "Help";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty braces `{}` that you use in the xaml are an escape sequence so the format is not interpreted as a markupextension by the parser. You don't need them in the codebehind - try this:

```
gvBinding.StringFormat = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt}";
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer and my problem is that I am feeding it a string rather than a date.  What it did was format the date before I put it in the string and then still bind to the string to solve my problem.  But I will build a test to feed the the GridView a date to test your solution so I can mark it as correct.